# How to get the max value for each group in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I've found some solutions for this problem, however, they don't seem to work with Oracle.

I got this:

[image]

I want a view  to present only the informations about the oldest person for each team. So, my output should be something like this:

```
PERSON  | TEAM | AGE
Sam     | 1    | 23
Michael | 2    | 21
```

How can I do that in Oracle?

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example without `keep` but with `row_number()`:

```
with t0 as
(
  select person, team, age,
  row_number() over(partition by team order by age desc) as rn
  from t
)
select person, team, age
from t0
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select * from table
where (team, age) in (select team, max(age) from table group by team)
```

Comment: From my testing, this is quite a bit slower than the other the other methods suggested here.

Answer (score 5):

One method uses `keep`:

```
select team, max(age) as age,
       max(person) keep (dense_rank first order by age desc) as person
from t
group by team;
```

There are other methods, but in my experience, `keep` works quite well.

Comment: This method works, however is there any simpler method? Teachers never taught us "keep"

Comment: I would consider this as being the simplest method from all answers you see here. However [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) is not that commonly known.

Comment: Good, but when I add more rows it expands. How to keep other columns for these rows I've queried?

Comment: @Peter.k . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results and explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (select person,team,age,
       dense_rank() over (partition by team order by age desc) rnk)
       where rnk=1;
```

Comment: Subselect here has no from clause. Looks invalid. This is not the select statement you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using an Analytic Function returns all people with maximum age per team (needed if there are people with identical ages), selects Table one time only and is thus faster than other solutions that reference Table multiple times:

```
With MaxAge as (
  Select T.*, Max (Age) Over (Partition by Team) MaxAge
  From Table T
)
Select Person, Team, Age From MaxAge Where Age=MaxAge
;
```

This also works in MySQL/MariaDB.